# Why is theme translate.csv not working dynamically for "My Cart (%s)"?

Tags: magento

I'm trying to translate "My Cart" to `"%s Items in Cart"` via `/my_theme/locale/en_US/translate.csv`.

I have a custom cart:

```
<?php $_cartQty = $this->getSummaryCount() ?>
<?php $cartText = (!empty($_cartQty)) ? $_cartQty : '0'; ?>
<li class="cart">
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart') ?>" class="cart-link"><?php echo $this->__('My Cart (' . $cartText . ')') ?></a>
```

All of the following are working fine:

```
"My Cart","0 Items in Cart"
"My Cart (0)","0 Items in Cart"
"My Cart (1)","1 Item in Cart"
"My Wishlist (%d items)","Wishlist (%d)"
"My Wishlist (%d item)","Wishlist (%d)"
"My Wishlist","Wishlist"
```

What's not working is:

```
"My Cart (%s)","%s Items in Cart"
"My Cart (%d)","%d Items in Cart"
```

Am I overlooking something ridiculous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use:

```
<?php echo $this->__('My Cart (%s)', $cartText) ?>
```

instead of:

```
<?php echo $this->__('My Cart (' . $cartText . ')') ?>
```

Comment: Use the line Detzee provided. You might have a look at app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Links.php how Magento handles 0 items / 1 item / x items in the default top menu link.

Answer (score 0):

Try use in translate.csv (it is example English to German):

```
"There are <a href=""%s"">%s items</a> in your cart.","Es sind <a href=""%s""><strong>%s Produkte</strong></a> in Ihrem Einkaufskorb."

"There is <a href=""%s"">1 item</a> in your cart.","Es ist <a href=""%s""><strong>1 Produkt</strong></a> in Ihrem Einkaufskorb."
```